# OpenCv: How to set a marker at a certain coordinate in a video stream open cv

Tags: c++, xcode, image-processing, opencv, openni

I'm working with NITE/OPENNI and opencv in xcode 4 to work with the kinect. I'm able to get the coordinates of the head for example this is done by :

In the main, outside the wile(true):

```
 IplImage *rgbimg = cvCreateImageHeader(cvSize(640,480), 8, 3);
```

Then in the wile(true)

```
XnSkeletonJointPosition Head;
g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().GetSkeletonJointPosition( aUsers[i], XN_SKEL_HEAD, Head); 
printf("%d: (%f,%f,%f) [%f]\n", aUsers[i], Head.position.X, Head.position.Y, Head.position.Z, Head.fConfidence); }
```

I also have a video stream :

```
    // Take current image
    const XnRGB24Pixel* pImage = Xn_image.GetRGB24ImageMap();

    //process image data
    XnRGB24Pixel* ucpImage = const_cast<XnRGB24Pixel*> (pImage);
    cvSetData(rgbimg,ucpImage, 640*3);
    cvCvtColor(rgbimg,rgbimg,CV_RGB2BGR);
    cvShowImage("RGB",rgbimg);
```

This is all done in the main in a while(true).

Now my question is how can i set some kind of marker (e.g.: *,cross-hair, X ) at the position of the coordinates of the hand in the video stream ?

**EDIT**

i tried:

```
XnRGB24Pixel* ucpImage = const_cast<XnRGB24Pixel*> (pImage);
cvSetData(rgbimg,ucpImage, 640*3);
cvCvtColor(rgbimg,rgbimg,CV_RGB2BGR);
cvCircle(rgbimg, cvPoint(Head.position.X,Head.position.Y), 20, cvScalar(0,255,0), 1);
cvShowImage("RGB",rgbimg);
```

and i get :

[image]

as you can see the circle stays in the top left corner for some reason. Any ideas how to change this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the display functions in OpenCV:

line(), circle(), drawPoly() and apply them to every frame in your video

Comment: For some reason, your point has the coordinates (0,0). The display part is ok, the problem is with detection.

Comment: As i can see from the output, you display there some negative coordinates (that is strange, on lines numbered 1) and the next line contains zeros. I assume you display the zero part